# Is there a way to pass local variables to includes in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, template-engine, ejs

I have a loop (below) inside of an include. I would like to place the contents of my loop of a partial, then pass the value of the loop's counter to my partial as a local variable:

```
<% for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { %>
    <!-- This is the code I would like to put inside a partial -->
    <div class="item-<%= i %>">
        <a class="item-img" href="#">
            <img src="<%= baseUrl %>/assets/img/tab-2/<%= myVar1 + i %>.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="item-info" href="#">
            <img src="<%= baseUrl %>/main/img/path/<%= myVar2 + i %>.png">
        </a>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

This is a relatively easy task in Haml but for some reason I keep getting an error in EJS. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?